# Android JSON with Volley and PHP End of input at character 0 of

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am writing an app that requires the use of storing contacts in a database so I am using wammp and PHPMyAdmin to write a simple REST API. I have written the parts that involve registering and logging in but for some reason I can not get the storing of contacts to work even though I thought it would be almost the same thing verbatim. I am getting the exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

I have looked around all over for this issue and it looks to be like the JSON that I am passing back to my app is empty, so I am aware of the problem but everywhere that I looked, the solutions did not help me actually fix the problem so I feel like it may be a unique problem. Here is my relevant Android code:

```
// Create the new string request
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_NEW_CONTACT, new Response.Listener<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response)
    {
        // Log method entry
        MethodLogger methodLogger = new MethodLogger();

        // Log the JSON that was returned
        methodLogger.d("New Contact Response: " + response.toString());

        // Remove the processing view
        hideDialog();

         // Try to retrieve JSON and parse through it
         try
         {
             JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

             // Check for errors in the JSON passed back
             boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

             /*----------------------------------------------------------------*
              *  If there was no error found                                   *
              *----------------------------------------------------------------*/
              if (!error)
              {
                  // Indicate the success to the user
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact successfully created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  // Take the user back to the contact page
                  routeToContactPage();
              }

              /*----------------------------------------------------------------*
               *  Else if there was an error found                              *
               *----------------------------------------------------------------*/
               else
               {
                   // Notify the user
                   String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                      errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
            }

            /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*
             * Catch any error in retrieving parsing etc JSON                     *
             *--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
             catch (JSONException e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error storing contact: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

             // Log method exit
             methodLogger.end();

         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener()
     {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
         {
              // Log method entry
              MethodLogger methodLogger = new MethodLogger();

              // Notify the user
              methodLogger.e("Error storing contact: " + error.getMessage());
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                     error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              hideDialog();

              // Log method exit
              methodLogger.end();
          }

      })
      {
           @Override
           protected Map<String, String> getParams()
           {
               // Log method entry
               MethodLogger methodLogger = new MethodLogger();

               // create a new params object and add the contact data
               Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

               // Add the params to the volley request
               params.put("user_id", SessionManager.getUser().getId());
               params.put("name", name);
               params.put("email", emailAddress);

               // Log method exit
               methodLogger.end();

               // Return the user data
               return params;
           }

      };

      // Send the request string to the request queue to be sent to the PHP API
      AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);
}
```

Relevant PHP Code:

Store the contact:

```
public function storeContact($name, $email, $user_id) 
{
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);

    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, "INSERT INTO contacts (unique_id, name, email, created_at, updated_at, user_id) VALUES ('$uuid', '$name', '$email', NOW(), NULL, '$user_id')") or die (mysql_error());

    if ($result) 
    {
        $contact = mysqli_query($this->conn, "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name = '$name' AND user_id = '$user_id'");

        return $contact;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Communicate with the server/app:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) 
{
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $result = $db->storeContact($name, $email, $user_id); 

    if ($result) 
    {
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["message"] = "Contact stored successfully";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["message"] = "Unknown error occurred in storing contact";
    }
} 
else 
{
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["message"] = "Required parameters, name, email, or user_id, missing";
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

and finally, relevant logcat output:

```
07-30 22:39:07.408 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.AppController: Method Entry: getInstance()
getInstance() finished in 0.000 seconds.
Method Entry: addToRequestQueue()
07-30 22:39:07.409 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.AppController: Method Entry: getRequestQueue()
getRequestQueue() finished in 0.000 seconds.
07-30 22:39:07.410 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.AppController: addToRequestQueue() finished in 0.001 seconds.
07-30 22:39:07.410 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.ContactActivity: onCreate() finished in 0.072 seconds.
07-30 22:39:07.424 24212-31569/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.ContactActivity$3: Method Entry: getParams()
07-30 22:39:07.425 24212-31569/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.ContactActivity$3: getParams() finished in 0.000 seconds.
07-30 22:39:07.426 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.NewContactActivity$1$1: Method Entry: onResponse()
onResponse() New Contact Response: 
07-30 22:39:07.426 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.NewContactActivity: Method Entry: hideDialog()
07-30 22:39:07.448 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.NewContactActivity: hideDialog() finished in 0.021 seconds.
07-30 22:39:07.448 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
    at com.example.e4977.spotme.NewContactActivity$1$1.onResponse(NewContactActivity.java:119)
07-30 22:39:07.449 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme W/System.err:     at com.example.e4977.spotme.NewContactActivity$1$1.onResponse(NewContactActivity.java:99)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
07-30 22:39:07.454 24212-24212/com.example.e4977.spotme D/com.example.e4977.spotme.NewContactActivity$1$1: onResponse() finished in 0.027 seconds.
```

Its also worth it to note that I see that the response is empty, I however do not know why. Here is the Database Schema in case that is part of the problem too.

[DBSchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtkSz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer

I'm fairly sure the reason for this is that you are using the `mysqli_*` set of functions but then attempting to get the latest error text using `mysql_error`, which will return an empty string as there have been no errors from calls to `mysql_*` functions.

Try replacing:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->conn, /* the rest */) or die (mysql_error());
```

with:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->conn, /* the rest */) or die (mysqli_error($this->conn));
```

You'll still get an exception thrown, similar to:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value Data of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

because the response will not be valid JSON, but this should help you on your way.

#### Side note

Because it's such a classic issue, I can't avoid commenting on the SQL injection issue in the code you've posted. It's worth having a read through https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html to understand the issue, and then taking a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for how to put together a safer implementation using `mysqli_prepare`, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` and `mysqli_stmt_execute`.

Comment: I've been busy and just got around to trying out what you gave and it just straight up fixed my problem. Very much appreciated! Now onto preventing the sql injection, thank you for pointing that out too.

Comment: Excellent, happy to help!